# Reset wm setting overrides

Tags: adb

A mere ~15 minutes ago I was messing with the "wm" command under android to get Avelog's Mouse Simulator to run better (this worked!).

Not knowing these overrides are persistent on these modern versions of android, I essentially soft locked myself out of the tablet by setting the density to 440.

Can't click "Allow" on the adb shell dialog, so THAT'S not an option!

The "wm" command also doesn't work under TWRP recovery.

Any help please? I don't intend to factory reset, even if it only means losing 30 minutes worth of data.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this took way WAY *WAY* too long to get an answer to. Modern android has SO MANY abstractions that it gets really difficult to find out what happens at the low level. Everything changing every major release (like partition layouts) does NOT help.

---

Open /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml:

> vi /data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml

Find the size override:

> /display_size_forced

Delete this line. Do the same with display_density_forced (...maybe?)

Write, sync, and reboot.

Despite messing with the density, I couldn't find that "display_density_forced" line anywhere in that file.

So... where is it? I don't know! Was able to boot up and run "wm density reset" though.